# Cast iron radiator holes

Tags: pipe, radiator, cast-iron

I have a family downstairs from me that cooks a lot of smelly foods. I noticed some smells are coming up from where the radiator pipe goes through the floor. I live on the 2nd floor.

I was wondering what I can use that can withstand the heat from the radiator to fill the gaps around the pipe and stop the smell.

Comment: It depends on the size of the gap/hole around the radiator pipes (a photo would sure help) but most likely any smell is coming up from more than one place and sealing the radiator won't really help that much.

Comment: aerobarrier might be a good option depending on your price point

Answer (score 1):

Most expandable foams are good up to 240 degrees F so I'd try some of that. Check the rating on the specific products if you're  interested in trying this.

Comment: Or just stuff fiberglass insulation around the pipe. It's not completely air-tight, but should effectively eliminate *any* smell. If you live in an apartment, you might not want to make a permanent change with expandable foam.

Comment: Depends on the size of the gap/hole.

Comment: Another option rated to the same temperature is firestop putty or caulk. Should be able to get it locally as well.

Comment: Expansion foam is not exactly permanent...